# Power Point "outline" view doesn't show or print text

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I try to print in outline view only text but when I set to outline view the
text from the slide disappears also when I try printing.
I'm trying to play with the fonts as but without any luck,
see image attached:
[image: no text in outline]

How can I set to see and print the text in outline view ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here.  Outline view displays text, but no graphics. That is its intended use, and your screen shot is clearly showing text. Also what do you mean by "I am trying to play with the fonts"? What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Can you please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/124493/edit) as it's not clear. Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't show as you can see in the left all the numbers as you see are empty

Answer (score 1):

The only text that appears (and prints) in Outline view is text that's in Title or Body Text placeholders (the things that say "Click here to ..." on newly created slides).

Often, people resent MS telling them what to click or where to put text and just delete these, or start with slides based on a blank layout, one that has no Title/Body placeholders. No text in these placeholders --> no text in the Outline view --> nothing to print as an outline.

For this and other reasons, it's generally best to work *with* PowerPoint rather than against it.  Generally. There are always exceptions to this rule, of course.